# XSLT Grouping flat XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I have a flat XML file that is coming from a database.  I need to group the data into a more hierarchical layout using an XSL transformation.  I have researched quite a bit and come up with Meunchian grouping as the way to go but can't get it to work.

I am going from:

```
<Report>
<Data>
    <Row>
        <Field name ="AssessmentID">1</Field>
        <Field name ="Company">Test Company</Field>
        <Field name ="Manager">Bob Smith</Field>
        <Field name ="IssueID">1-1</Field>
        <Field name ="IssueTitle">Security Problem</Field>
        <Field name ="IssueDescription">Some Description</Field>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Field name ="AssessmentID">1</Field>
        <Field name ="Company">Test Company</Field>
        <Field name ="Manager">Bob Smith</Field>
        <Field name ="IssueID">1-2</Field>
        <Field name ="IssueTitle">Other Problem</Field>
        <Field name ="IssueDescription">Some Other Description</Field>
    </Row>
</Data>
</Report>
```

To this:

```
<Assessments>
<Assessment>
    <AssessmentID>1</AssessmentID>
    <Company>Test Company</Company>
    <Manager>Bob Smith</Manager>
    <Issue>
        <IssueID>1-1</IssueID>
        <IssueTitle>Security Problem</IssueTitle>
        <IssueDescription>Some Description</IssueDescription>
    </Issue>
    <Issue>
        <IssueID>1-2</IssueID>
        <IssueTitle>Other Problem</IssueTitle>
        <IssueDescription>Some Other Description</IssueDescription>
    </Issue>
</Assessment>
</Assessments>
```

This is the code I've come up with so far:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:key name="keyAssessmentID" match="Row" use="Field[@name='AssessmentID']"/>
        <xsl:key name="keyIssueID" match="Row" use="Field[@name='IssueID']"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Assessments>
            <!-- Process each Assessment -->
        <xsl:for-each select="//Row[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('keyAssessmentID', Field[@name='AssessmentID'])[1])]">
                <!-- Select all the issues belonging to the assessment -->
                    <xsl:variable name ="lngAssessmentID"><xsl:value-of select="Field[@name='AssessmentID']" /></xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:variable name="lstIssue" select="//Row[Field[@name='IssueID']=$lngAssessmentID]" />

                    <!-- show details for Issues in Assessments -->
                    <xsl:call-template name="ShowIssuesInAssessment">
                        <xsl:with-param name="lstIssue" select="$lstIssue" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>             
        </Assessments>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="ShowIssuesInAssessment">
        <xsl:param name="lstIssue" />

        <!-- Show the name of the Assessment currently being processed -->
        <AssessmentID>
            <xsl:value-of select="$lstIssue[1]/Field[@name='AssessmentID']" />
        </AssessmentID>

 <!-- Show IssueID for each Issue in the Assessment -->
 <xsl:for-each select="$lstIssue[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('keyIssueID', Field[@Name='IssueID'])[1])]">
  <xsl:variable name="lngIssueID" select="Field[@Name='IssueID']" />
  <!-- Show details of each Issue -->
  <Issue>
    <IssueID>
        <xsl:value-of select="$lstIssue[Field[@Name='IssueID']=$lngIssueID]/Field[@Name='IssueID']" />
     </IssueID>
     <IssueTitle>
            <xsl:value-of select="$lstIssue[Field[@Name='IssueID']=$lngIssueID]/Field[@Name='IssueTitle']" />
   </IssueTitle>
   </Issue>
     </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am working off of this example on CodeProject:  [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1849/Grouping-XML-using-XSLT)

Thanks all for any assistance!

Comment: Wheres your XSLT code, that you can't get to work

Comment: OJay, this is my first StackOverflow post, thanks for the coaching on etiquette.  I posted the XSL and the example I have been using.

Comment: Do you need to group on **IssueID** as well as **AssessmentID**? That is to say, can you have the same **IssueID** occurring more than once in the file for a given **AssessmentID**?

Comment: The Issue ID is unique to each issue and will not be repeated in a given assessment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've started off correctly by using Muenchian Grouping to get the first occurrence of each **AssessmentID**

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Row[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('keyAssessmentID', Field[@name='AssessmentID'])[1])]">
```

But to get all the "issues" for an assessment, you should be actually using the key (where **$AssessmentId** is the variable containing the AssessmentId)

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('keyAssessmentID', $AssessmentId)"/>
```

I can't see any need to use **xsl:call-template** here, or to pass in the elements in the group as a parameter. Just use template matching, which is what XSLT is good at. Then in the template that matches **Row**, you can output the issue details

```
<xsl:template match="Row">
   <Issue>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Field[@name='IssueID']"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Field[@name='IssueTitle']"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Field[@name='IssueDescription']"/>
   </Issue>
</xsl:template>
```

And to save code repetition you can have a single template matching these variable fields

```
<xsl:template match="Row/*">
   <xsl:element name="{@name}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

(This makes use of "Attribute Value Templates" to create the element name based on the value of the **@name** attribute for the field).

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="keyAssessmentID" match="Row" use="Field[@name='AssessmentID']"/>

   <xsl:template match="/*">
      <Assessments>
         <xsl:for-each select=".//Row[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('keyAssessmentID', Field[@name='AssessmentID'])[1])]">
            <xsl:variable name="AssessmentId" select="Field[@name='AssessmentID']"/>
            <Assessment>
               <AssessmentID>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$AssessmentId"/>
               </AssessmentID>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="key('keyAssessmentID', $AssessmentId)"/>
            </Assessment>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </Assessments>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Row">
      <Issue>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="Field[@name='IssueID']"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="Field[@name='IssueTitle']"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="Field[@name='IssueDescription']"/>
      </Issue>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Row/*">
      <xsl:element name="{@name}">
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then, have a read of http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html to get a better understanding of Muenchian Grouping.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help Tim C.  I really appreciate the explanation as to how this works, it really helped improve my understanding of the transformation logic.

Answer (score 0):

Brilliant answer by @Tim C, but I thought I would add mine for a slightly different angle. I think the point was that you seemed to be using the keyIssueID key in there as well, which is not really needed, based on your suggested output, you only needed to have a key of AssessmentID

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:key name="keyAssessmentID" match="Row" use="./Field[@name='AssessmentID']"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="Assessments">
      <xsl:for-each select="//Row[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('keyAssessmentID',Field[@name='AssessmentID']))]">
        <xsl:element name="Assesment">
          <xsl:variable name="AssessmentId" select="./Field[@name='AssessmentID']" />
          <xsl:element name="AssessmentId">
            <xsl:value-of select="$AssessmentId"/>
          </xsl:element>
          <xsl:element name="Company">
            <xsl:value-of select="./Field[@name='Company']"/>
          </xsl:element>
          <xsl:element name="Manager">
            <xsl:value-of select="./Field[@name='Manager']"/>
          </xsl:element>
          <xsl:for-each select="key(keyAssessmentID,$AssessmentId)">
            <xsl:element name="Issue">
              <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::Field[contains(@name,'Issue')]">
                <xsl:element name="{./@name}">
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:element>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: OJay, I really appreciate the alternate solution.  I am new to XSL transformation and this was very helpful to take apart and figure out how it is working.